# How to find an ubuntu password which i removed?

Tags: 12.04, password-recovery

I removed my password from the user menu where they gave the option for no password. So i pressed that and now the computer can be logged into but they ask a password which is not my old password....What should i do? I am quite new to Ubuntu....

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/878997) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/882255), where setting the no password login also removes the password therefore using `sudo` etc. is impossible. The link given by @Rohit is essential to re-create your lost password. If you can still login however, you can open up the terminal; usually <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `passwd` to change your password.

Comment: `passwd` assumes you want to change your own password if you don't specify any arguments.

Comment: Right, It's just that I'm used to run `passwd` with root. Hence the username. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link to resolve your issue[How to reset your password](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword) or this [with new OS](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/02/reset-your-forgotten-password-quickly.html)

I personally suggest to have password, even if small but strong and secret